# create DNS zone entry in an azure template across resource group

Tags: azure, dns, azure-resource-manager

I have a template that creates a VM with a publicIP in Azure.
I now want to add a DNS record to my Domain zonefile controlled also by azure in DNSzones but it belongs to another resource group ?

I dont think this is possible although it would be a very common thing to do having often done this with other cloud providers. I did ask microsoft support but they didnt know. Maybe use terraform instead of azure templates??? Has anyone made this work ?

Answer (score 1):

Today, Azure DNS does not support creating DNS records 'by reference', e.g. pointing to a resource such as a PublicIpAddress or Web App.  This is on our roadmap as a future feature, but I can't share an ETA at this stage.

Instead, you need to create DNS records specifying the DNS details such as the IP address explicitly.  To avoid possible IP address changes, you might want to consider using a reserved PublicIpAddress.

There is no restriction on creating DNS zones in a different resource group from your other Azure services.  Since DNS records are a child of the DNS zone, they will reside in the same resource group as the zone.

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure DNS